# how do keep mapped data seperate during flatmap

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
files = sc.wholeTextFiles("/path/to/data*")
//files is of length N
x = files.map(lambda x: x[1])
//x is of length N with disregarding path name
y = x.flatMap(lambda p: p.split('\n'))
```

`y` is a collection of all lines, I would like this split into `N` parts, rather than it be aggergated to one, to preserve which lines are in which original file. So if currently, my `y` value has 10000 items, and I have 10 files.  I want `y` to have 10 items, and each item is a collection containing the lines for that particular file.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

@asdasd2a43qaad

If I understood correct, You can achieve this with `map` instead of `flatMap` on `x`

`y = x.map(lambda p: p.split('\n'))`

Hope this helps